# how to assign list of values of attribute to single attribute in R

Tags: r

Am at beginner stage of R programming, please help me in below issue. 
I have different desc values assigned to the same sol attribute in different rows. I want to make all desc values of sol attribute in single row as mentioned below
My data is as follows:

```
sol          desc

  1       fry, toast                                                                                             
  1    frt,grt,gty

1   ytr,uyt,ytr    

6   hyt, ytr,oiu

4    hyg,hyu,loi

4    opu,yut,yut

I want the output as follows :

sol         desc

1        fry,toast,frt,grt,gty,ytr,uyt,yir  

6        hyt, ytr,oiu

4        hyg,hyu,loi,opu,yut,yut
```

Note: you can input any values in desc as per your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate()` is what you are looking for. Try this:

```
aggregate(desc ~ sol, data = df, paste, collapse = ",")
  sol                               desc
1   1 fry, toast,frt,grt,gty,ytr,uyt,ytr
2   4            hyg,hyu,loi,opu,yut,yut
3   6                       hyt, ytr,oiu
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(sol = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L), desc = c("fry, toast", 
"frt,grt,gty", "ytr,uyt,ytr", "hyt, ytr,oiu", "hyg,hyu,loi", 
"opu,yut,yut")), .Names = c("sol", "desc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```